# Video Embed Field with Magnific Popup

Tags: 8, entities, media

I'm trying to display an embedded video in a popup window using the [Magnific Popup Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/magnific_popup/). For the video field, I'm using [Video Embed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_field).The popup window works with images trouble-free. However when I try to set up the display with the video field (Magnific Popup formatter), the throbber keeps turning and I'm not able to save this configuration. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue.
the problem was in the module:

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException:
>   You have requested a non-existent service "colorbox.attachment";.

The module mantainer do not add colorbox to dependencies.

So you just to need to install and enable Colorbox module.

Comment: I already had forgotten that project. Thanks @Romix, that did the trick!

Comment: This was a bug fixed in https://www.drupal.org/project/magnific_popup/issues/2794479